# What is the proper way to use Any type in gRPC message field?

Tags: python, grpc

My message is defined like this:

```
    import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

    service TSSwitch {
       rpc start_ts_analytic (StartTSAnalyticRequest) returns (SwitchResponse) {}
    }

    message StartTSAnalyticRequest {
        google.protobuf.Any config = 4;
    }
```

I've already implemented in client side as below:

```
    from google.protobuf.any_pb2 import Any

    config = {
            "a": true,
            "b": [[576, 667, 360, 998],
                           [1483, 940, 1348, 676]],
            "c": [0,600, 1500, 600],
            "helmet_violation": false
        }

    cfg = Any().Pack(config)
    req = switch_pb2.StartTSAnalyticRequest(config=cfg)
```

But after executing, I've got error like this in client side:

```
   'BaseDict' object has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

What did I do incorrectly? Please give me a hand on this prolem :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `Any` proto doesn't mean a proto message that can encode any Python objects, instead it is a proto message that is capable of packing any other proto messages with their types.

In your use case, if you want to pass a dictionary, you may consider:

1. Create a proto message for you config;
2. Encode the config into bytes (JSON/Pickle) and save them in one of the proto message field.